# Solving $\int_{-1}^{1}8x^3-5x^2+4dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I've done the following so far:

$$\left.\int_{-1}^{1}\left(8x^3-5x^2+4\right)dx=\left(\frac{8}{4}x^4-\frac{5}{3}x^3+4x\vphantom{\int}\right)\right|_{-1}^{1}$$
$$=\left(\frac{8}{4}-\frac{5}{3}+4\right)=\frac{13}{3}$$

However, I double-checked on wolfram alpha and the solution is actually $-\dfrac{14}{3}$. Would you know where I went wrong? I have no idea where the negative came from, in the solution, or how it's one value above mine.

Comment: $f(x)|_{-1}^1=f(1)-f(-1)$.

Comment: See the correct comment of the user Surb. Fundamental theorem of Torricelli-Barrow's integral calculation.

Comment: All the suggestions here are correct, btw your incorrect answer is actually integrating from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: The $x^3$ term, being of odd degree, doesn't contribute to an integral on a region of the form $[-a,\,a]$, so you could have saved yourself some work.

Comment: You integrated from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: "I double-checked on wolfram alpha": can we see your query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of last limit must be $4-(-4)=8$
$$\int_{-1}^1(8x^3-5x^2+4)dx=\left(4x^4-\frac53x^3+4x\right)_{-1}^1$$
$$=\left(4(1)^4-\frac53(1)^3+4(1)-4(-1)^4+\frac53(-1)^3-4(-1)\right) $$
$$=\frac{14}{3}$$

Comment: Approved also your complete solution! 

Answer (score 5):

Well, you forgot to subtract the value of that integral at the lower limit.

Comment: You can tell this in comments also. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Just a fast answer:
$$\int_{-1}^{1}8x^3-5x^2+4dx=\int _{-1}^18x^3dx-\int _{-1}^15x^2dx+\int _{-1}^14dx=0-\frac{10}{3}+8=\frac{14}3$$

**Corollary**:
Let be $f\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb R$ a continuous function that it has an antiderivates (primitive)) $G$ on $[a,b]$ iff exists $G(x)$ with:

$$G'(x) = f(x)$$

Then if $f$ is integrable we have

$$\int_a^b f(x)\mathop{}\!\mathrm dx=G(b)- G(a)$$

Answer (score 3):

As $x^3$ is odd, the integral of $\int_{-1}^{1}8x^3\,dx$ is zero. Therefore

\begin{align}\int_{-1}^{1}\left(8x^3-5x^2+4\right)dx&=\int_{-1}^{1}(-5x^2+4)\,dx\\&=\left(\frac{-5x^3}{3}+4x\right)\Bigg|_{-1}^{1}\\&=\left(\frac{-5}{3}+4\right)-\left(\frac{5}{3}-4\right)\\&=\frac{24-10}{3}\\&=\frac{14}{3}.\end{align}